# Создание ресурсных файлов в Delphi 10.3 для X64 платформы

Tags: delphi, локализация

Ресурсы собираются только под win32. Выбора платформы у ресурсных проектов нету. В XE5 была а в 10.3 убрали. Подскажите где искать?

Comment: Что такое ресурсный проект?

Comment: Там вроде можно добавить платформу для сборки, если её нет по-умолчанию.

Comment: ресурсный проект это проект для ресурсной dll. В это dll содержатся ресурсы (строки и  т.д.) различные для разных языков.  Данные проекты создаются через меню Project->Languagues->Add. Вот у этого в новь появившегося проекта отсутствует в дереве меню для Bild Configuration и Targrt Platform. А собранная dll не подгружается к  exe собранному для 64win. Падает на вызове DllLoad. Ни кто не локализовывал на  Delphi 10.3 проекты?

Comment: Ситуация крайне странная получается. Собранные EXE файлы под win64 и win32 читают строки с этой ресурсной dll и перевод отображается нормально. Но хотелось бы собрать dll именно под Win64.  Так как она подгружается к через dllLoad в стороннее приложение написанное на  с++.

Comment: Вы что-то путаете - 64-х битный exe не может загрузить 32-х битную dll. Разрядности exe и dll должны совпадать.

Comment: @zed Есть чудесная опция LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE, которая заставлят LoadLibraryEx загрузить из DLL ресурсы, но не исполнять код из нее. Имеено так можно заставить 64 битное приложение загрузить ресурсы из 32битной dll

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию Delphi создает проекты "Dynamic Library" только под платформу Win32. Но в дереве проекта (View -> Tool Windows -> Projects) можно кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши по ветке "Target Platforms" и выбрать "Add Platform...". Там будет "Windows 64-bit"